# ¿Cuál es el mejor lugar para colocar los tag <scripts src=""> en HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Recientemente tuve un problema al llamar los scripts de JQuery en un pequeño script de php, por lo general los coloco después de la etiqueta body así:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
</html>
```

Esto para evitar que se demore la carga de los demás elementos de la página.

El problema es que estaba haciendo una especie de template con 3 archivos php:

1. header.php
2. menus.php
3. footer.php

En el `header` llamo todos los elementos `head`, por ejemplo `css`, `meta`, `title`; en menús creo el menú que será visible en todas las páginas, y en `footer` tengo el pie de pagina y los tag `<script>`, pero al momento de realizar algunas otra páginas y llamar alguna función de JQuery me lanza un error:

> $ no está definido

La solución fue colocar todos estos scripts en el `header`. De tal manera que primero se cargan estos scripts y luego las etiquetas restantes.

He revisado esta pregunta en SO inglés:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436411/where-is-the-best-place-to-put-script-tags-in-html-markup

Sin embargo al cargarse asincronamente los scripts externos, hay ocasiones en las que sale el mismo error citado anteriormente.

Mi pregunta es: **¿Cuál es la mejor ubicación para colocar estos tags?** ya que hasta ahora lo que me ha solucionado ese problema es mantenerlos en la cabecera.¿O debería pensar en otra manera de hacer el template en PHP?

Comment: Después de leer las respuestas que hay hasta ahora, considero que sería bueno que las basaran en datos, documentos o demostraciones técnicas, no solo en gustos personales. Veo un par de respuestas que están orientadas de esa manera.

Comment: Mira, cuando tengas una duda sobre HTML, usa el [validator](https://validator.w3.org/) para que no tengas problemas con la sintaxis. Porque realmente la duda no radica en javascript sino en HTML5.

Answer (score 89):

En primer lugar, el script es una etiqueta de HTML que debe ser incluida en el header o en el body, no puede incluirse fuera, por esa razon no puedes acceder a Jquery.

Debes reemplazar:

```
</body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
```

Por esto:

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 
</body>
```

#### ¿Cuál es el mejor lugar para color las etiquetas script?

**Debes evitar poner los scripts en el header.** El renderizado e interpretacion del `HTML` se realiza a medida que el navegador encuentra los elementos en tu documento `HTML`. Por lo tanto si encuentra en la cabecera una etiqueta `script`, pues tendrá que esperar a que el navegador cargue el `script` para continuar con el renderizado de la pagina por lo que verías el navegador con la pantalla en blanco, comportamiento que uno desea evitar.

> Adicionalmente, el comportamiento de los scripts se ven afectados por
>   el uso de los atributos **async y defer**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Etiqueta Script sin ningun atributo

Cuando definimos una etiqueta `script` sin ningún atributo el `HTML` será interpretado hasta que encuentre la etiqueta `script`, en ese punto la interpretación se detendrá y solicitará el `archivo js`(en caso sea externo), una vez que tengamos cargado el archivo entonces este sera ejecutado antes de que se continué interpretando el `HTML`. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Async

El atributo `async` permite que el navegador descargue el archivo `script asíncronamente`(de ahí el nombre,sorprendente no?) y continuar con la interpretación del `HTML`, a penas termine con la descarga interrumpirá la interpretación para empezar la ejecución del `script` e inmediatamente después continuará con el proceso de interpretación.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Defer

El atributo `defer` a diferencia de `async`, aplaza(defer) la ejecución del `script` después de que la interpretación del `HTML` ha concluido, la descarga se realiza de forma asíncrona igual que en el caso anterior pero defer nos **garantiza ejecutar los scripts en el orden** en el que aparecen en nuestro documento, a diferencia de `async` que los ejecuta a penas termina de descargar.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### ¿Cómo decidir entre usar async o defer?

Te recomiendo leer https://somostechies.com/async-vs-defer.

Comment: esta debería ser la respuesta aceptada...

Comment: Sería bueno añadir algo más a la sección de "¿Cómo decidir entre usar async o defer?". Los enlaces se rompen y dejan de funcionar y puede ser una parte interesante de la respuesta.

Comment: La respuesta es completa pero hay algo en lo que no estoy de acuerdo. Si bien es verdad que los recursos en el head deben ser cargados completamente (si no tienen async o defer) antes de renderizar la página, solo debería evitarse la inclusión de recursos en el head si realmente existe un tiempo perceptible para el usuario en el que la página está sin renderizar. De hecho, hay librerías (como Twitter Bootstrap) que parten de la base de que se incluirán en el head (no hacerlo puede causar un renderizado no deseado).

Answer (score 16):

Esto está mal:

> ```
> </body>
> <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
> ```

Los scripts, por norma general se deben colocar **antes** del cierre del body. Sin embargo, hay casos particulares en donde es conveniente ponerlos en el header.

**¿Cuál es el proceso de renderizado de un documento HTML?**

1. Parseo del documento
2. Encuentra una etiqueta `script` con una archivo externo.
   2.1 Carga el script y **detiene** la carga del documento hasta que el script haya sido completamente cargado.
3. Se ejecutan los scripts.
4. Finaliza la carga del documento.

---

**¿Cuándo usar async/defer?**

`Async` te permite cargar un script asíncronamente, es decir, **no detiene** la carga del documento y es ejecutado ni bien es cargado.

Supongamos el siguiente escenario:

```
<script async src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script async src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

En este caso, bootstrap **puede** ejecutarse antes que jquery.

`Defer` tampoco es bloqueante, pero a diferencia de `async` **sí respeta** el orden de los scripts.

**¿Cuándo es correcto poner los scripts en el header?**

Una práctica habitual es también poner los scripts en el `header` con `async` o `defer`, de este modo, los scripts son obtenidos inmediatamente cuando empieza el parseo pero sin bloquear el mismo.

Answer (score 9):

La integración de `JavaScript` y `XHTML` es muy flexible, ya que existen al menos tres formas para incluir código `JavaScript` en las páginas web.

**Incluir JavaScript en el mismo documento XHTML**

El código `JavaScript` se encierra entre etiquetas `<script>` y se incluye en cualquier parte del documento. Aunque es correcto incluir cualquier bloque de código en cualquier zona de la página, se recomienda definir el código `JavaScript` dentro de la cabecera del documento (dentro de la etiqueta `<head>`):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Ejemplo de código JavaScript en el propio documento</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
  alert("Un mensaje de prueba");
</script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Un párrafo de texto.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Para que la página XHTML resultante sea válida, es necesario añadir el atributo `type` a la etiqueta `<script>`. Los valores que se incluyen en el atributo `type` están estandarizados y para el caso de `JavaScript`, el valor correcto es `text/javascript`.

Este método se emplea cuando se define un bloque pequeño de código o cuando se quieren incluir instrucciones específicas en un determinado documento `HTML` que completen las instrucciones y funciones que se incluyen por defecto en todos los documentos del sitio web.

El principal inconveniente es que si se quiere hacer una modificación en el bloque de código, es necesario modificar todas las páginas que incluyen ese mismo bloque de código `JavaScript`.

**Definir JavaScript en un archivo externo**

Las instrucciones JavaScript se pueden incluir en un archivo externo de tipo `JavaScript` que los documentos `XHTML` enlazan mediante la etiqueta `<script>`. Se pueden crear todos los archivos `JavaScript` que sean necesarios y cada documento `XHTML` puede enlazar tantos archivos `JavaScript` como necesite.

Ejemplo:

Archivo `codigo.js`

`alert("Un mensaje de prueba");`

Documento `XHTML`

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Ejemplo de código JavaScript en el propio documento</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/codigo.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<p>Un párrafo de texto.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Además del atributo `type`, este método requiere definir el atributo src, que es el que indica la `URL` correspondiente al archivo `JavaScript` que se quiere enlazar. Cada etiqueta `<script>` solamente puede enlazar un único archivo, pero en una misma página se pueden incluir tantas etiquetas `<script>` como sean necesarias.

Los archivos de tipo `JavaScript` son documentos normales de texto con la extensión `.js`, que se pueden crear con cualquier editor de texto como `Notepad`, `Wordpad`, `EmEditor`, `UltraEdit`, `Vi`, etc.

La principal ventaja de enlazar un archivo `JavaScript` externo es que se simplifica el código `XHTML` de la página, que se puede reutilizar el mismo código `JavaScript` en todas las páginas del sitio web y que cualquier modificación realizada en el archivo `JavaScript` se ve reflejada inmediatamente en todas las páginas `XHTML` que lo enlazan.

**Incluir JavaScript en los elementos XHTML**

Este último método es el menos utilizado, ya que consiste en incluir trozos de `JavaScript` dentro del código `XHTML` de la página:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Ejemplo de código JavaScript en el propio documento</title>
</head>

<body>
<p onclick="alert('Un mensaje de prueba')">Un párrafo de texto.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

El mayor inconveniente de este método es que ensucia innecesariamente el código `XHTML` de la página y complica el mantenimiento del código `JavaScript`. En general, este método sólo se utiliza para definir algunos eventos y en algunos otros casos especiales, como se verá más adelante.

Answer (score 8):

Para mi, en este momento es mejor ponerlos antes del cierre de la etiqueta `body` como se menciona en [una respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/436425/3100840)

Simplemente por una razón, `async` es solo soportado en `Internet Explorer 10+` por tanto hay muchos usuario que pudieran tener problemas, aparte es una característica de `HTML5` por tanto algunos exploradores viejos también se verán afectados.

Claro que en algunos años esto no importará por que los usuarios de `IE` probablemente pasen a `Microsoft Edge` donde ya está soportado, incluidos updates en otros navegadores, simplemente ya no se justificará.

Por otro lado, si tienes problemas con librerias como `jQuery`, deberías revisar el output de tu página, seguramente se ejecuta algo donde no.

Como yo utilizo mis platillas tengo una sección de de estilos y 3 para los `scripts`, **imports**, **ready**, **functions**

1. **imports** donde agrego los `<script src ...`
2. **ready** donde hay un `document.ready` esto para solo tener uno siempre.
3. **functions** por si hay alguna funcion que no quiera meter dentro de de algún js por x o y razón

Espero te ayude

Answer (score 7):

El problema que planteas no es la posición de elementos `script`, sino del orden de ejecución de la página.

En `xHTML` los elementos `script` deberían colocarse dentro del elemento `head`. A partir de HTML 5 es menos restrictivo y puede colocarse donde se quiera; se recomienda situarlos como últimos elementos, eso permite que todo el DOM esté cargado antes de intentar ejecutar nada y hace prescindibles métodos como `ready()`.

Utilizar propiedades `defer` o `async` no lo resolverán, estás retrasan la carga del elemento al que afectan.

Tu problema sucede por el orden de carga/ejecución: tienes algún fragmento de código que intenta usar el alias de jQuery (`$`) antes de que se cargue el propio jQuery. Coloca el resto de tu código JavaScript después de la carga de jQuery.

Danos una muestra mas completa de tu código si no consigues resolverlo.

Answer (score 6):

Hay teorías para todos los gustos. A mi personalmente, me gusta mas ponerlos antes de la etiqueta `</body>`

Uno de los motivos, es que aunque falle, la codificación `javascript`, la página se va a cargar de todas formas, aunque a veces, lo he tenido que cargar en el `head`, porque sino la página me fallaba

Answer (score 2):

Lo mejor siempre es colocar los "scripts" antes del cierre de "body" y después de todo tu contenido HTML div, a, span, etc, debido a que por lo general haces llamado a los elementos por ID o Clase y deben estar cargados antes de comenzar a ejecutarse.

Otra cosa que también debes tomar en cuenta a la hora de incluir tus "scripts" es colocar las dependencias primero, por ejemplo

...

```
</div><! Cierre de tu último tag HTML de contenido -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script-que-usa-jquery-como-dependencia.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Con esto evitaras el mensaje de

> $ no está definido

debido a que jquery estará cargando antes de comenzar a ejecutar "script-que-usa-jquery-como-dependencia.js".

Answer (score 2):

La pregunta es algo debatible ya que influye mucho lo que haga la página al momento de iniciar.

En mi experiencia es poner los .css en el `<head>` y los .js al final del `<body>` similar a lo siguiente

```
<head>
<link href="mynew.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>
... mi html
<script src="myJavaScript.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<body>
```

ya que los css se cargan al principio para darle la interfaz a la pagina, y la funcionalidad que son los js se agregan al final, ya que muchas veces no se necesita funcionalidad al iniciar, de igual manera al estar de ultimo la carga es más rápida pues muestra la información al usuario, a pesar de no haber cargado la funcionalidad.

También comento que si llegas a necesitar que se ejecute una función al abrir la página puede incluir el js de dicha función en el head.

Espero te sirva de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Lo habitual es organizarlo de forma que se cargue en orden aunque le pongas 'asinc'

```
<html>
<head>
<script>"Carga de frameworks y js internos, lo primordial
 es que la librería de jquery este en cabeza y si lo tienes en local mejor, así no dependes del estado del repositorio"</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function (){"funciones de inicio que se cargan al cargar todo el html, esto es sobre todo para funciones que toquen DOM o que dependan de el"}</script>
</head>
<body>Aquí dentro nada de js jamás</body>
<script>Funciones que no requieren una carga al inicio, como .clicks/.hover y demás</script>
</html>
```

Más o menos así es como solemos organizar por aquí las app. Lo esencial es que todo lo que puedas meter en un js externo, dentro de la carpeta js, lo pongas ahí y en el html escribas solo lo indispensable.

Answer (score -1):

Lo más acertado seria colocar los scripts justo en el final del  empezando por las librerias y complementos como por ejemplo jquery y acabando con tus scripts propios. Tambien seria recomendable empezar a ejecutar el contenido del script una vez se haya cargado la pagina siempre que sea posible. Por ejemplo usando jquery lo podrias hacer asi:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    iniciar();
});

function iniciar() {
    // aqui iria tu script
}
```