# Cambio de color de botón Bootstrap

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Tengo una pequeña aplicación que tiene un botón creado con Bootstrap:

```
<input id="boton" type="submit" name="proceso" class="btn btn-success" value="Proceso">
```

Mi idea es que al pulsar el botón una vez, cambie de color o cambie la clases bootstrap a:

```
class="btn btn-danger"
```

Si vuelvo a pulsar, pues que me vuelva a `btn-success`

Tengo que tener en cuenta de que los usuarios hacen login, es decir que si pulsan el botón y el botón se pone rojo, cuando vuelvan a entrar en la aplicación, el botón debe seguir estando rojo.

¿Alguna ayuda? Gracias!

Comment: y que as intentando hasta ahora??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usando la función [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) obtienes el evento de pulsar el botón y capturando la clase con `.attr('class')` puedes saber que tienes puesto y modificarlo con el siguiente ejemplo:

```js
        $("#boton").click(function () {           
        
            var clase = $('#boton').attr('class');

            if (clase.includes("btn-success")) {                        
                $('#boton').removeClass('btn-success');
                $('#boton').addClass('btn-danger');
            } else {
                $('#boton').removeClass('btn-danger');
                $('#boton').addClass('btn-success');
            }           
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<input id="boton" type="submit" name="proceso" class="btn btn-success" value="Proceso">
```

Comment: En el el input, ¿tengo que llamar a la función esa no?

Comment: @Maginon No hace falta, con `$('#boton')` ya lo capturas, puedes verlo ejecutando el ejemplo

Comment: La ultima. El código jquery, ¿es mejor ponerlo en un script arriba del documento no?

Comment: Te dejo este [enlace](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25088/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-mejor-lugar-para-colocar-los-tag-scripts-src-en-html) que lo explica bastante bien

Comment: Muchas gracias! Me ha sido de gran ayuda!

Answer (score 2):

Para lo que intentas hacer puedes usar la propiedad **[classList](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_classlist.asp)** de un elemento. Esto devuelve un array con las clases que tenga el item. Luego los vas cambiando entre uno y otro a medida que clickees.

Si quieres cambiar de color, solo basta con tener un css que cambie el color por cada clase.

```js
let togg = true

function changeClass(btn){
  if (togg) {
    btn.classList.remove('btn-success');
    btn.classList.add('btn-danger');  
  }else {
    btn.classList.remove('btn-danger');  
    btn.classList.add('btn-success');
  }
  togg = !togg;
  
  console.log(btn.classList[0]+' '+btn.classList[1]);
}
```

```html
<input id="boton" type="submit" name="proceso" class="btn btn-success" value="Proceso" onclick="changeClass(this);">
```

Comment: Intenté esto y también funcionaba, aunque mi idea se parecía más a la otra respuesta. De todas formas, muchas gracias por tu tiempo!