# Html NO ejecuta archivo javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

Resulta que tengo un proyecto sencillo el que corresponde a un juego *Pinball*, el cual no ejecuta mi archivo `JavaScript`. 
Esto lo confirme debido a que el código lo saque de **CodePen** y cuando extraigo solo el código de `JavaScript` queda igual que lo que me muestra a mi en el navegador.

[Pen original](https://codepen.io/lonekorean/pen/KXLrVX)

El editor de código que estoy utilizando es **Visual Stuidio Code** detallo códigos
Intente con otros proyectos simples pero aun así no me funciona en general los archivos `JavaScript`

```js
(() => {
 // plugins
 Matter.use(MatterAttractors);

 // constants
 const PATHS = {
  DOME: '0 0 0 250 19 250 20 231.9 25.7 196.1 36.9 161.7 53.3 129.5 74.6 100.2 100.2 74.6 129.5 53.3 161.7 36.9 196.1 25.7 231.9 20 268.1 20 303.9 25.7 338.3 36.9 370.5 53.3 399.8 74.6 425.4 100.2 446.7 129.5 463.1 161.7 474.3 196.1 480 231.9 480 250 500 250 500 0 0 0',
  DROP_LEFT: '0 0 20 0 70 100 20 150 0 150 0 0',
  DROP_RIGHT: '50 0 68 0 68 150 50 150 0 100 50 0',
  APRON_LEFT: '0 0 180 120 0 120 0 0',
  APRON_RIGHT: '180 0 180 120 0 120 180 0'
 };
 const COLOR = {
  BACKGROUND: '#212529',
  OUTER: '#495057',
  INNER: '#15aabf',
  BUMPER: '#fab005',
  BUMPER_LIT: '#fff3bf',
  PADDLE: '#e64980',
  PINBALL: '#dee2e6'
 };
 const GRAVITY = 0.75;
 const WIREFRAMES = false;
 const BUMPER_BOUNCE = 1.5;
 const PADDLE_PULL = 0.002;
 const MAX_VELOCITY = 50;

 // score elements
 let $currentScore = $('.current-score span');
 let $highScore = $('.high-score span');

 // shared variables
 let currentScore, highScore;
 let engine, world, render, pinball, stopperGroup;
 let leftPaddle, leftUpStopper, leftDownStopper, isLeftPaddleUp;
 let rightPaddle, rightUpStopper, rightDownStopper, isRightPaddleUp;

 function load() {
  init();
  createStaticBodies();
  createPaddles();
  createPinball();
  createEvents();
 }

 function init() {
  // engine (shared)
  engine = Matter.Engine.create();

  // world (shared)
  world = engine.world;
  world.bounds = {
   min: { x: 0, y: 0},
   max: { x: 500, y: 800 }
  };
  world.gravity.y = GRAVITY; // simulate rolling on a slanted table

  // render (shared)
  render = Matter.Render.create({
   element: $('.container')[0],
   engine: engine,
   options: {
    width: world.bounds.max.x,
    height: world.bounds.max.y,
    wireframes: WIREFRAMES,
    background: COLOR.BACKGROUND
   }
  });
  Matter.Render.run(render);

  // runner
  let runner = Matter.Runner.create();
  Matter.Runner.run(runner, engine);

  // used for collision filtering on various bodies
  stopperGroup = Matter.Body.nextGroup(true);

  // starting values
  currentScore = 0;
  highScore = 0;
  isLeftPaddleUp = false;
  isRightPaddleUp = false;
 }

 function createStaticBodies() {
  Matter.World.add(world, [
   // table boundaries (top, bottom, left, right)
   boundary(250, -30, 500, 100),
   boundary(250, 830, 500, 100),
   boundary(-30, 400, 100, 800),
   boundary(530, 400, 100, 800),

   // dome
   path(239, 86, PATHS.DOME),

   // pegs (left, mid, right)
   wall(140, 140, 20, 40, COLOR.INNER),
   wall(225, 140, 20, 40, COLOR.INNER),
   wall(310, 140, 20, 40, COLOR.INNER),

   // top bumpers (left, mid, right)
   bumper(105, 250),
   bumper(225, 250),
   bumper(345, 250),

   // bottom bumpers (left, right)
   bumper(165, 340),
   bumper(285, 340),

   // shooter lane wall
   wall(440, 520, 20, 560, COLOR.OUTER),

   // drops (left, right)
   path(25, 360, PATHS.DROP_LEFT),
   path(425, 360, PATHS.DROP_RIGHT),

   // slingshots (left, right)
   wall(120, 510, 20, 120, COLOR.INNER),
   wall(330, 510, 20, 120, COLOR.INNER),

   // out lane walls (left, right)
   wall(60, 529, 20, 160, COLOR.INNER),
   wall(390, 529, 20, 160, COLOR.INNER),

   // flipper walls (left, right);
   wall(93, 624, 20, 98, COLOR.INNER, -0.96),
   wall(357, 624, 20, 98, COLOR.INNER, 0.96),

   // aprons (left, right)
   path(79, 740, PATHS.APRON_LEFT),
   path(371, 740, PATHS.APRON_RIGHT),

   // reset zones (center, right)
   reset(225, 50),
   reset(465, 30)
  ]);
 }

 function createPaddles() {
  // these bodies keep paddle swings contained, but allow the ball to pass through
  leftUpStopper = stopper(160, 591, 'left', 'up');
  leftDownStopper = stopper(140, 743, 'left', 'down');
  rightUpStopper = stopper(290, 591, 'right', 'up');
  rightDownStopper = stopper(310, 743, 'right', 'down');
  Matter.World.add(world, [leftUpStopper, leftDownStopper, rightUpStopper, rightDownStopper]);

  // this group lets paddle pieces overlap each other
  let paddleGroup = Matter.Body.nextGroup(true);

  // Left paddle mechanism
  let paddleLeft = {};
  paddleLeft.paddle = Matter.Bodies.trapezoid(170, 660, 20, 80, 0.33, {
   label: 'paddleLeft',
   angle: 1.57,
   chamfer: {},
   render: {
    fillStyle: COLOR.PADDLE
   }
  });
  paddleLeft.brick = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(172, 672, 40, 80, {
   angle: 1.62,
   chamfer: {},
   render: {
    visible: false
   }
  });
  paddleLeft.comp = Matter.Body.create({
   label: 'paddleLeftComp',
   parts: [paddleLeft.paddle, paddleLeft.brick]
  });
  paddleLeft.hinge = Matter.Bodies.circle(142, 660, 5, {
   isStatic: true,
   render: {
    visible: false
   }
  });
  Object.values(paddleLeft).forEach((piece) => {
   piece.collisionFilter.group = paddleGroup
  });
  paddleLeft.con = Matter.Constraint.create({
   bodyA: paddleLeft.comp,
   pointA: { x: -29.5, y: -8.5 },
   bodyB: paddleLeft.hinge,
   length: 0,
   stiffness: 0
  });
  Matter.World.add(world, [paddleLeft.comp, paddleLeft.hinge, paddleLeft.con]);
  Matter.Body.rotate(paddleLeft.comp, 0.57, { x: 142, y: 660 });

  // right paddle mechanism
  let paddleRight = {};
  paddleRight.paddle = Matter.Bodies.trapezoid(280, 660, 20, 80, 0.33, {
   label: 'paddleRight',
   angle: -1.57,
   chamfer: {},
   render: {
    fillStyle: COLOR.PADDLE
   }
  });
  paddleRight.brick = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(278, 672, 40, 80, {
   angle: -1.62,
   chamfer: {},
   render: {
    visible: false
   }
  });
  paddleRight.comp = Matter.Body.create({
   label: 'paddleRightComp',
   parts: [paddleRight.paddle, paddleRight.brick]
  });
  paddleRight.hinge = Matter.Bodies.circle(308, 660, 5, {
   isStatic: true,
   render: {
    visible: false
   }
  });
  Object.values(paddleRight).forEach((piece) => {
   piece.collisionFilter.group = paddleGroup
  });
  paddleRight.con = Matter.Constraint.create({
   bodyA: paddleRight.comp,
   pointA: { x: 29.5, y: -8.5 },
   bodyB: paddleRight.hinge,
   length: 0,
   stiffness: 0
  });
  Matter.World.add(world, [paddleRight.comp, paddleRight.hinge, paddleRight.con]);
  Matter.Body.rotate(paddleRight.comp, -0.57, { x: 308, y: 660 });
 }

 function createPinball() {
  // x/y are set to when pinball is launched
  pinball = Matter.Bodies.circle(0, 0, 14, {
   label: 'pinball',
   collisionFilter: {
    group: stopperGroup
   },
   render: {
    fillStyle: COLOR.PINBALL
   }
  });
  Matter.World.add(world, pinball);
  launchPinball();
 }

 function createEvents() {
  // events for when the pinball hits stuff
  Matter.Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', function(event) {
   let pairs = event.pairs;
   pairs.forEach(function(pair) {
    if (pair.bodyB.label === 'pinball') {
     switch (pair.bodyA.label) {
      case 'reset':
       launchPinball();
       break;
      case 'bumper':
       pingBumper(pair.bodyA);
       break;
     }
    }
   });
  });

  // regulate pinball
  Matter.Events.on(engine, 'beforeUpdate', function(event) {
   // bumpers can quickly multiply velocity, so keep that in check
   Matter.Body.setVelocity(pinball, {
    x: Math.max(Math.min(pinball.velocity.x, MAX_VELOCITY), -MAX_VELOCITY),
    y: Math.max(Math.min(pinball.velocity.y, MAX_VELOCITY), -MAX_VELOCITY),
   });

   // cheap way to keep ball from going back down the shooter lane
   if (pinball.position.x > 450 && pinball.velocity.y > 0) {
    Matter.Body.setVelocity(pinball, { x: 0, y: -10 });
   }
  });

  // mouse drag (god mode for grabbing pinball)
  Matter.World.add(world, Matter.MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
   mouse: Matter.Mouse.create(render.canvas),
   constraint: {
    stiffness: 0.2,
    render: {
     visible: false
    }
   }
  }));

  // keyboard paddle events
  $('body').on('keydown', function(e) {
   if (e.which === 37) { // left arrow key
    isLeftPaddleUp = true;
   } else if (e.which === 39) { // right arrow key
    isRightPaddleUp = true;
   }
  });
  $('body').on('keyup', function(e) {
   if (e.which === 37) { // left arrow key
    isLeftPaddleUp = false;
   } else if (e.which === 39) { // right arrow key
    isRightPaddleUp = false;
   }
  });

  // click/tap paddle events
  $('.left-trigger')
   .on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    isLeftPaddleUp = true;
   })
   .on('mouseup touchend', function(e) {
    isLeftPaddleUp = false;
   });
  $('.right-trigger')
  .on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    isRightPaddleUp = true;
   })
   .on('mouseup touchend', function(e) {
    isRightPaddleUp = false;
   });
 }

 function launchPinball() {
  updateScore(0);
  Matter.Body.setPosition(pinball, { x: 465, y: 765 });
  Matter.Body.setVelocity(pinball, { x: 0, y: -25 + rand(-2, 2) });
  Matter.Body.setAngularVelocity(pinball, 0);
 }

 function pingBumper(bumper) {
  updateScore(currentScore + 10);

  // flash color
  bumper.render.fillStyle = COLOR.BUMPER_LIT;
  setTimeout(function() {
   bumper.render.fillStyle = COLOR.BUMPER;
  }, 100);
 }

 function updateScore(newCurrentScore) {
  currentScore = newCurrentScore;
  $currentScore.text(currentScore);

  highScore = Math.max(currentScore, highScore);
  $highScore.text(highScore);
 }

 // matter.js has a built in random range function, but it is deterministic
 function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
 }

 // outer edges of pinball table
 function boundary(x, y, width, height) {
  return Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x, y, width, height, {
   isStatic: true,
   render: {
    fillStyle: COLOR.OUTER
   }
  });
 }

 // wall segments
 function wall(x, y, width, height, color, angle = 0) {
  return Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x, y, width, height, {
   angle: angle,
   isStatic: true,
   chamfer: { radius: 10 },
   render: {
    fillStyle: color
   }
  });
 }

 // bodies created from SVG paths
 function path(x, y, path) {
  let vertices = Matter.Vertices.fromPath(path);
  return Matter.Bodies.fromVertices(x, y, vertices, {
   isStatic: true,
   render: {
    fillStyle: COLOR.OUTER,

    // add stroke and line width to fill in slight gaps between fragments
    strokeStyle: COLOR.OUTER,
    lineWidth: 1
   }
  });
 }

 // round bodies that repel pinball
 function bumper(x, y) {
  let bumper = Matter.Bodies.circle(x, y, 25, {
   label: 'bumper',
   isStatic: true,
   render: {
    fillStyle: COLOR.BUMPER
   }
  });

  // for some reason, restitution is reset unless it's set after body creation
  bumper.restitution = BUMPER_BOUNCE;

  return bumper;
 }

 // invisible bodies to constrict paddles
 function stopper(x, y, side, position) {
  // determine which paddle composite to interact with
  let attracteeLabel = (side === 'left') ? 'paddleLeftComp' : 'paddleRightComp';

  return Matter.Bodies.circle(x, y, 40, {
   isStatic: true,
   render: {
    visible: false,
   },
   collisionFilter: {
    group: stopperGroup
   },
   plugin: {
    attractors: [
     // stopper is always a, other body is b
     function(a, b) {
      if (b.label === attracteeLabel) {
       let isPaddleUp = (side === 'left') ? isLeftPaddleUp : isRightPaddleUp;
       let isPullingUp = (position === 'up' && isPaddleUp);
       let isPullingDown = (position === 'down' && !isPaddleUp);
       if (isPullingUp || isPullingDown) {
        return {
         x: (a.position.x - b.position.x) * PADDLE_PULL,
         y: (a.position.y - b.position.y) * PADDLE_PULL,
        };
       }
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  });
 }

 // contact with these bodies causes pinball to be relaunched
 function reset(x, width) {
  return Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x, 781, width, 2, {
   label: 'reset',
   isStatic: true,
   render: {
    fillStyle: '#fff'
   }
  });
 }

 window.addEventListener('load', load, false);
})();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind');

*, *::before, *::after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

body {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 margin: 0;
 color: #dee2e6;
 background-color: #212529;
 font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
 position: relative;
 line-height: 0;
}

.score {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 line-height: 1;
}

.score span {
 font-size: 3.25rem;
}

.current-score {
 left: 10px;
}

.high-score {
 text-align: right;
 right: 10px;
}

.trigger {
  appearance: none;
 position: absolute;
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 bottom: 10px;
  border: 0;
 border-radius: 50%;
  color: inherit;
 background-color: #e64980;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 80px;
 font-size: 1.25rem;
  text-transform: inherit;
 cursor: pointer;
 user-select: none;
  outline: none;
}

.left-trigger {
 left: 10px;
}

.right-trigger {
 right: 60px;
}

canvas {
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

/* responsive scaling, because pinball tables are tall */
@media (min-height: 0px) {
 .container { transform: scale(0.25); }
}
@media (min-height: 400px) {
 .container { transform: scale(0.5); }
}
@media (min-height: 600px) {
 .container { transform: scale(0.75); }
}
@media (min-height: 800px) {
 .container { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="css\stilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="js\app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="score current-score">
      score<br><span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="score high-score">
      high score<br><span></span>
    </div>
    <button class="trigger left-trigger">tap!</button>
    <button class="trigger right-trigger">tap!</button>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Podrías poner el enlace al CodePen original? Parece que usa librerias externas como `Mater.js`, en el CodePen puedes ver todo lo que utiliza y lo que necesitaras para que te funcione el código.

Comment: Por supuesto! aqui va: https://codepen.io/lonekorean/pen/KXLrVX

Comment: En el navegador hay una opción para mostrar el código fuente de la página, en esa misma ventana encuentra la consola y ahí se muestra el error que tienes con el javascript.

Comment: y porque no le das a la opcion exportar en codepen eso te descarga los archivos completos y el codigo del mismo `:v`

Comment: Muchas Gracias!! asi logre ver que era lo que ocurria!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cuando veas un código de un **Pen** es importante conocer si usa librerias/scripts externos: Puedes ver esto en Settings (Opciones) y en las pestañas de CSS y JS. 
Los de `CSS` tendrías que enlazarlos con `<link>` y los `JS` con `<script>`

Tienes que poner los siguientes `<script>` en tu código en el `html`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/schteppe/poly-decomp.js/1ef946f1/build/decomp.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/liabru/matter-js/0895d81f/build/matter.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/liabru/matter-attractors/c470ed42/build/matter-attractors.min.js"></script>
```

Yo los he puesto antes del cierre del body (lo recomendado), por lo que deberías de poner el `script` de tu `JS` local después de estos.

[¿Cuál es el mejor lugar para colocar los tag  en HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25088/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-mejor-lugar-para-colocar-los-tag-scripts-src-en-html)

**Snippet con los scripts:**

```js
(() => {
 // plugins
 Matter.use(MatterAttractors);

 // constants
 const PATHS = {
  DOME: '0 0 0 250 19 250 20 231.9 25.7 196.1 36.9 161.7 53.3 129.5 74.6 100.2 100.2 74.6 129.5 53.3 161.7 36.9 196.1 25.7 231.9 20 268.1 20 303.9 25.7 338.3 36.9 370.5 53.3 399.8 74.6 425.4 100.2 446.7 129.5 463.1 161.7 474.3 196.1 480 231.9 480 250 500 250 500 0 0 0',
  DROP_LEFT: '0 0 20 0 70 100 20 150 0 150 0 0',
  DROP_RIGHT: '50 0 68 0 68 150 50 150 0 100 50 0',
  APRON_LEFT: '0 0 180 120 0 120 0 0',
  APRON_RIGHT: '180 0 180 120 0 120 180 0'
 };
 const COLOR = {
  BACKGROUND: '#212529',
  OUTER: '#495057',
  INNER: '#15aabf',
  BUMPER: '#fab005',
  BUMPER_LIT: '#fff3bf',
  PADDLE: '#e64980',
  PINBALL: '#dee2e6'
 };
 const GRAVITY = 0.75;
 const WIREFRAMES = false;
 const BUMPER_BOUNCE = 1.5;
 const PADDLE_PULL = 0.002;
 const MAX_VELOCITY = 50;

 // score elements
 let $currentScore = $('.current-score span');
 let $highScore = $('.high-score span');

 // shared variables
 let currentScore, highScore;
 let engine, world, render, pinball, stopperGroup;
 let leftPaddle, leftUpStopper, leftDownStopper, isLeftPaddleUp;
 let rightPaddle, rightUpStopper, rightDownStopper, isRightPaddleUp;

 function load() {
  init();
  createStaticBodies();
  createPaddles();
  createPinball();
  createEvents();
 }

 function init() {
  // engine (shared)
  engine = Matter.Engine.create();

  // world (shared)
  world = engine.world;
  world.bounds = {
   min: { x: 0, y: 0},
   max: { x: 500, y: 800 }
  };
  world.gravity.y = GRAVITY; // simulate rolling on a slanted table

  // render (shared)
  render = Matter.Render.create({
   element: $('.container')[0],
   engine: engine,
   options: {
    width: world.bounds.max.x,
    height: world.bounds.max.y,
    wireframes: WIREFRAMES,
    background: COLOR.BACKGROUND
   }
  });
  Matter.Render.run(render);

  // runner
  let runner = Matter.Runner.create();
  Matter.Runner.run(runner, engine);

  // used for collision filtering on various bodies
  stopperGroup = Matter.Body.nextGroup(true);

  // starting values
  currentScore = 0;
  highScore = 0;
  isLeftPaddleUp = false;
  isRightPaddleUp = false;
 }

 function createStaticBodies() {
  Matter.World.add(world, [
   // table boundaries (top, bottom, left, right)
   boundary(250, -30, 500, 100),
   boundary(250, 830, 500, 100),
   boundary(-30, 400, 100, 800),
   boundary(530, 400, 100, 800),

   // dome
   path(239, 86, PATHS.DOME),

   // pegs (left, mid, right)
   wall(140, 140, 20, 40, COLOR.INNER),
   wall(225, 140, 20, 40, COLOR.INNER),
   wall(310, 140, 20, 40, COLOR.INNER),

   // top bumpers (left, mid, right)
   bumper(105, 250),
   bumper(225, 250),
   bumper(345, 250),

   // bottom bumpers (left, right)
   bumper(165, 340),
   bumper(285, 340),

   // shooter lane wall
   wall(440, 520, 20, 560, COLOR.OUTER),

   // drops (left, right)
   path(25, 360, PATHS.DROP_LEFT),
   path(425, 360, PATHS.DROP_RIGHT),

   // slingshots (left, right)
   wall(120, 510, 20, 120, COLOR.INNER),
   wall(330, 510, 20, 120, COLOR.INNER),

   // out lane walls (left, right)
   wall(60, 529, 20, 160, COLOR.INNER),
   wall(390, 529, 20, 160, COLOR.INNER),

   // flipper walls (left, right);
   wall(93, 624, 20, 98, COLOR.INNER, -0.96),
   wall(357, 624, 20, 98, COLOR.INNER, 0.96),

   // aprons (left, right)
   path(79, 740, PATHS.APRON_LEFT),
   path(371, 740, PATHS.APRON_RIGHT),

   // reset zones (center, right)
   reset(225, 50),
   reset(465, 30)
  ]);
 }

 function createPaddles() {
  // these bodies keep paddle swings contained, but allow the ball to pass through
  leftUpStopper = stopper(160, 591, 'left', 'up');
  leftDownStopper = stopper(140, 743, 'left', 'down');
  rightUpStopper = stopper(290, 591, 'right', 'up');
  rightDownStopper = stopper(310, 743, 'right', 'down');
  Matter.World.add(world, [leftUpStopper, leftDownStopper, rightUpStopper, rightDownStopper]);

  // this group lets paddle pieces overlap each other
  let paddleGroup = Matter.Body.nextGroup(true);

  // Left paddle mechanism
  let paddleLeft = {};
  paddleLeft.paddle = Matter.Bodies.trapezoid(170, 660, 20, 80, 0.33, {
   label: 'paddleLeft',
   angle: 1.57,
   chamfer: {},
   render: {
    fillStyle: COLOR.PADDLE
   }
  });
  paddleLeft.brick = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(172, 672, 40, 80, {
   angle: 1.62,
   chamfer: {},
   render: {
    visible: false
   }
  });
  paddleLeft.comp = Matter.Body.create({
   label: 'paddleLeftComp',
   parts: [paddleLeft.paddle, paddleLeft.brick]
  });
  paddleLeft.hinge = Matter.Bodies.circle(142, 660, 5, {
   isStatic: true,
   render: {
    visible: false
   }
  });
  Object.values(paddleLeft).forEach((piece) => {
   piece.collisionFilter.group = paddleGroup
  });
  paddleLeft.con = Matter.Constraint.create({
   bodyA: paddleLeft.comp,
   pointA: { x: -29.5, y: -8.5 },
   bodyB: paddleLeft.hinge,
   length: 0,
   stiffness: 0
  });
  Matter.World.add(world, [paddleLeft.comp, paddleLeft.hinge, paddleLeft.con]);
  Matter.Body.rotate(paddleLeft.comp, 0.57, { x: 142, y: 660 });

  // right paddle mechanism
  let paddleRight = {};
  paddleRight.paddle = Matter.Bodies.trapezoid(280, 660, 20, 80, 0.33, {
   label: 'paddleRight',
   angle: -1.57,
   chamfer: {},
   render: {
    fillStyle: COLOR.PADDLE
   }
  });
  paddleRight.brick = Matter.Bodies.rectangle(278, 672, 40, 80, {
   angle: -1.62,
   chamfer: {},
   render: {
    visible: false
   }
  });
  paddleRight.comp = Matter.Body.create({
   label: 'paddleRightComp',
   parts: [paddleRight.paddle, paddleRight.brick]
  });
  paddleRight.hinge = Matter.Bodies.circle(308, 660, 5, {
   isStatic: true,
   render: {
    visible: false
   }
  });
  Object.values(paddleRight).forEach((piece) => {
   piece.collisionFilter.group = paddleGroup
  });
  paddleRight.con = Matter.Constraint.create({
   bodyA: paddleRight.comp,
   pointA: { x: 29.5, y: -8.5 },
   bodyB: paddleRight.hinge,
   length: 0,
   stiffness: 0
  });
  Matter.World.add(world, [paddleRight.comp, paddleRight.hinge, paddleRight.con]);
  Matter.Body.rotate(paddleRight.comp, -0.57, { x: 308, y: 660 });
 }

 function createPinball() {
  // x/y are set to when pinball is launched
  pinball = Matter.Bodies.circle(0, 0, 14, {
   label: 'pinball',
   collisionFilter: {
    group: stopperGroup
   },
   render: {
    fillStyle: COLOR.PINBALL
   }
  });
  Matter.World.add(world, pinball);
  launchPinball();
 }

 function createEvents() {
  // events for when the pinball hits stuff
  Matter.Events.on(engine, 'collisionStart', function(event) {
   let pairs = event.pairs;
   pairs.forEach(function(pair) {
    if (pair.bodyB.label === 'pinball') {
     switch (pair.bodyA.label) {
      case 'reset':
       launchPinball();
       break;
      case 'bumper':
       pingBumper(pair.bodyA);
       break;
     }
    }
   });
  });

  // regulate pinball
  Matter.Events.on(engine, 'beforeUpdate', function(event) {
   // bumpers can quickly multiply velocity, so keep that in check
   Matter.Body.setVelocity(pinball, {
    x: Math.max(Math.min(pinball.velocity.x, MAX_VELOCITY), -MAX_VELOCITY),
    y: Math.max(Math.min(pinball.velocity.y, MAX_VELOCITY), -MAX_VELOCITY),
   });

   // cheap way to keep ball from going back down the shooter lane
   if (pinball.position.x > 450 && pinball.velocity.y > 0) {
    Matter.Body.setVelocity(pinball, { x: 0, y: -10 });
   }
  });

  // mouse drag (god mode for grabbing pinball)
  Matter.World.add(world, Matter.MouseConstraint.create(engine, {
   mouse: Matter.Mouse.create(render.canvas),
   constraint: {
    stiffness: 0.2,
    render: {
     visible: false
    }
   }
  }));

  // keyboard paddle events
  $('body').on('keydown', function(e) {
   if (e.which === 37) { // left arrow key
    isLeftPaddleUp = true;
   } else if (e.which === 39) { // right arrow key
    isRightPaddleUp = true;
   }
  });
  $('body').on('keyup', function(e) {
   if (e.which === 37) { // left arrow key
    isLeftPaddleUp = false;
   } else if (e.which === 39) { // right arrow key
    isRightPaddleUp = false;
   }
  });

  // click/tap paddle events
  $('.left-trigger')
   .on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    isLeftPaddleUp = true;
   })
   .on('mouseup touchend', function(e) {
    isLeftPaddleUp = false;
   });
  $('.right-trigger')
  .on('mousedown touchstart', function(e) {
    isRightPaddleUp = true;
   })
   .on('mouseup touchend', function(e) {
    isRightPaddleUp = false;
   });
 }

 function launchPinball() {
  updateScore(0);
  Matter.Body.setPosition(pinball, { x: 465, y: 765 });
  Matter.Body.setVelocity(pinball, { x: 0, y: -25 + rand(-2, 2) });
  Matter.Body.setAngularVelocity(pinball, 0);
 }

 function pingBumper(bumper) {
  updateScore(currentScore + 10);

  // flash color
  bumper.render.fillStyle = COLOR.BUMPER_LIT;
  setTimeout(function() {
   bumper.render.fillStyle = COLOR.BUMPER;
  }, 100);
 }

 function updateScore(newCurrentScore) {
  currentScore = newCurrentScore;
  $currentScore.text(currentScore);

  highScore = Math.max(currentScore, highScore);
  $highScore.text(highScore);
 }

 // matter.js has a built in random range function, but it is deterministic
 function rand(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
 }

 // outer edges of pinball table
 function boundary(x, y, width, height) {
  return Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x, y, width, height, {
   isStatic: true,
   render: {
    fillStyle: COLOR.OUTER
   }
  });
 }

 // wall segments
 function wall(x, y, width, height, color, angle = 0) {
  return Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x, y, width, height, {
   angle: angle,
   isStatic: true,
   chamfer: { radius: 10 },
   render: {
    fillStyle: color
   }
  });
 }

 // bodies created from SVG paths
 function path(x, y, path) {
  let vertices = Matter.Vertices.fromPath(path);
  return Matter.Bodies.fromVertices(x, y, vertices, {
   isStatic: true,
   render: {
    fillStyle: COLOR.OUTER,

    // add stroke and line width to fill in slight gaps between fragments
    strokeStyle: COLOR.OUTER,
    lineWidth: 1
   }
  });
 }

 // round bodies that repel pinball
 function bumper(x, y) {
  let bumper = Matter.Bodies.circle(x, y, 25, {
   label: 'bumper',
   isStatic: true,
   render: {
    fillStyle: COLOR.BUMPER
   }
  });

  // for some reason, restitution is reset unless it's set after body creation
  bumper.restitution = BUMPER_BOUNCE;

  return bumper;
 }

 // invisible bodies to constrict paddles
 function stopper(x, y, side, position) {
  // determine which paddle composite to interact with
  let attracteeLabel = (side === 'left') ? 'paddleLeftComp' : 'paddleRightComp';

  return Matter.Bodies.circle(x, y, 40, {
   isStatic: true,
   render: {
    visible: false,
   },
   collisionFilter: {
    group: stopperGroup
   },
   plugin: {
    attractors: [
     // stopper is always a, other body is b
     function(a, b) {
      if (b.label === attracteeLabel) {
       let isPaddleUp = (side === 'left') ? isLeftPaddleUp : isRightPaddleUp;
       let isPullingUp = (position === 'up' && isPaddleUp);
       let isPullingDown = (position === 'down' && !isPaddleUp);
       if (isPullingUp || isPullingDown) {
        return {
         x: (a.position.x - b.position.x) * PADDLE_PULL,
         y: (a.position.y - b.position.y) * PADDLE_PULL,
        };
       }
      }
     }
    ]
   }
  });
 }

 // contact with these bodies causes pinball to be relaunched
 function reset(x, width) {
  return Matter.Bodies.rectangle(x, 781, width, 2, {
   label: 'reset',
   isStatic: true,
   render: {
    fillStyle: '#fff'
   }
  });
 }

 window.addEventListener('load', load, false);
})();
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind');

*, *::before, *::after {
 box-sizing: border-box;
}

html, body {
 height: 100%;
 overflow: hidden;
}

body {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
 align-items: center;
 margin: 0;
 color: #dee2e6;
 background-color: #212529;
 font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;
 text-transform: uppercase;
}

.container {
 position: relative;
 line-height: 0;
}

.score {
 position: absolute;
 top: 10px;
 line-height: 1;
}

.score span {
 font-size: 3.25rem;
}

.current-score {
 left: 10px;
}

.high-score {
 text-align: right;
 right: 10px;
}

.trigger {
  appearance: none;
 position: absolute;
 width: 80px;
 height: 80px;
 bottom: 10px;
  border: 0;
 border-radius: 50%;
  color: inherit;
 background-color: #e64980;
 text-align: center;
 line-height: 80px;
 font-size: 1.25rem;
  text-transform: inherit;
 cursor: pointer;
 user-select: none;
  outline: none;
}

.left-trigger {
 left: 10px;
}

.right-trigger {
 right: 60px;
}

canvas {
 overflow: hidden;
 border-radius: 5px;
 box-shadow: 0 5px 25px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
}

/* responsive scaling, because pinball tables are tall */
@media (min-height: 0px) {
 .container { transform: scale(0.25); }
}
@media (min-height: 400px) {
 .container { transform: scale(0.5); }
}
@media (min-height: 600px) {
 .container { transform: scale(0.75); }
}
@media (min-height: 800px) {
 .container { transform: scale(1); }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="css\stilos.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="score current-score">
      score<br><span></span>
    </div>
    <div class="score high-score">
      high score<br><span></span>
    </div>
    <button class="trigger left-trigger">tap!</button>
    <button class="trigger right-trigger">tap!</button>
  </div>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/schteppe/poly-decomp.js/1ef946f1/build/decomp.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/liabru/matter-js/0895d81f/build/matter.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/liabru/matter-attractors/c470ed42/build/matter-attractors.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js\app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: este script `<script src="js\app.js"></script>`  tambien deberia ir luego de los 4 tags que has añadido y no el `head`

Comment: @ajuni880 Editado, buen ojo! gracias :)

Comment: Genial! muchas gracias!! me resulto inmediatamente luego de agregar las librerias y ademas dejarlo dentro del body!

Comment: @ajuni880 cual es la diferencial de colocar el script en el body y no en el head?

Comment: @Alluka en esta pregunta se explica [¿Cuál es el mejor lugar para colocar los tag <scripts src=“”> en HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/25088/128699), ponerlos al final del `body` te puede evitar problemas como que se ejecute un `script` antes de que se cree el elemento del `DOM`.

Comment: Para entenderlo mejor deberías leer algun articulo sobre como el navegador renderiza el html. Pero simplificandolo, es porque el html se renderiza de arriba a abajo y si pones el script en el `head` pues el navegador parseará el script y lo ejecutará y si en dicho `script` haces referencia a un elemento del body pues este no exisitira aún porque aun no se ha llegado al body y puede dar errores. Por eso se linkan los scripts propios al final, los scripts de terceros se pueden agregar en el `head`.

Comment: @ajuni880 los `scripts` de terceros también pueden usar elementos del `dom` normalmente mediante clases. Por lo que también pueden ocasionar estos problemas. En general es algo bastante especifico para cada caso.

Comment: @x3kagainstSEbehavior tienes razón depende mucho de los casos pero suelen ser librerias que no manipulan el `DOM` sino que tu las usas en tus scripts. Como ajax, jquery. Pero si tienes razón depende del caso.