# ¿Cuál es el "lugar" correcto de colocar la etiqueta <script> en HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, script

Me ha surgido la duda, usualmente colocaba la etiqueta `<script>` en el `<head>`, y en la practica, realicé el siguiente código a la página:

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
console.log(links.length);
```

Y aunque hayan varias etiquetas `<a>` en la página, me retornó 0. Probé cambiar el `<script>` de lugar, esta vez lo puse antes de finalizar el `</body>` y me funcionó correctamente, retornándome cuantas etiquetas `<a>` había.

No sé a que se deba esto, tal vez al estar la etiqueta `<script>` en el `<head>` ejecute todo el código antes de que el documento HTML haya cargado, y al estar antes de finalizar el `<body>` retorne lo esperado porque ya cargo el HTML, la verdad no sé, es una suposición, en resumen:

1- ¿Cuál es el lugar correcto para colocar la etiqueta `<script>`?

2- A que se debió este comportamiento de mi código, algo parecido a lo que mencioné más arriba?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [¿Cuál es el mejor lugar para colocar los tag <scripts src=""> en HTML?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/25088/cu%c3%a1l-es-el-mejor-lugar-para-colocar-los-tag-scripts-src-en-html)

Comment: Ten en cuenta una cosa. Da absolutamente igual qué tag sea, las páginas html ***SIEMPRE*** son interpretadas desde el inicio hasta el fin. Así que obviamente el código que se interpreta primero, no sabe qué va a venir después!

Comment: Depende de la ejecución, aunque tambien puedes especificar en cualquier lugar si quieres que se ejecute cuando el dom o algún elemento se haya terminado de cargar.

Answer (score 1):

Lo recomendable es usar dentro del body al final de la etiqueta de cierre de dicha etiqueta

colocarlo dentro de  puede ayudar a mejorar la velocidad de carga, ya que el contenido del sitio web se cargará más rápido, después de todo ello  se procesará el JavaScript entonces ahi tienes la respuesta de tu pregunta lo que surgio es que  aun no habia cargado todas las etiquetas  la pagina y antes de que cargara realizo el proceso que seria este

```
var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
console.log(links.length);
```

es decir el proceso se hizo tal cual,pero como no encontro aun las etiquetas cargadas no retorno el dato esperado

Dios te bendiga saludos y feliz dia